# Robolectric simple test

Tags: android, robolectric

I was trying to test a very simple calculator app with Robolectric.

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    mActivity = new MainActivity();
    mActivity.onCreate(new Bundle());

    et1 = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(com.mamlambo.article.simplecalc.R.id.value1);
    et2 = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(com.mamlambo.article.simplecalc.R.id.value2);

    btnAdd = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(com.mamlambo.article.simplecalc.R.id.addValues);
    btnMult = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(com.mamlambo.article.simplecalc.R.id.multiplyValues);

    result = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(com.mamlambo.article.simplecalc.R.id.result);


}

@Test
public void test(){


    et1.setText("20");
    et2.setText("20");

    btnAdd.performClick();

    assertThat("40", equalTo(result.getText().toString()));
}
```

But after running the test the assertion says

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: ""
          got: "40"
```

I am guessing that the EditText is not getting set. I have tried it with and without `TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE` but it makes no difference.

Can someone tell me what is it that i am doing wrong ? I'm pretty sure that its something extremely simple but i'm just not able to see what it is :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Robolectric 2.x, and have annotated your test class with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`, what if you do:

```
mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
```

instead of:

```
mActivity = new MainActivity();
mActivity.onCreate(new Bundle());
```

Comment: Still the same :( I'm using Robolectric 2.1 and i have annotated the class with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`. I'm guessing it has something to do with where and how i set `et1` and `et2`.